# Creación dinámica de tablas en SQL Server desde Azure Data Factory con datos de Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, blob, azure-storage

Estoy intentando cargar datos de archivos CSV o TXT almacenados en Azure Blob Storage a una tabla en SQL Server utilizando Azure Data Factory. Lo que necesito es una forma de que la tabla en SQL Server se cree dinámicamente con columnas genéricas, basándose en el esquema de los datos del archivo de origen, en lugar de tener que predefinir la tabla en SQL Server.

Hasta donde sé, Azure Data Factory no soporta la creación de tablas sobre la marcha. ¿Ha habido algún cambio reciente en esta funcionalidad que debería conocer?

Si no, ¿hay alguna solución alternativa para lograr esto? ¿Podría, por ejemplo, hacer uso de Azure Data Lake, Azure Databricks o Azure Synapse Analytics para manejar los esquemas de datos dinámicos de forma más eficiente?

Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada

Comment: Hola Juan. con respecto a tu pregunta *"¿Ha habido algún cambio?"*, viene la follow-up question *¿Qué has investigado?*. Si quieres columnas dinámicas, me parece que tendrás que crear un proceso que lea los csv, cree las columnas, y luego haga el insert. Tal vez otra opción sea utilizar NoSQL (Azure Cosmos DB), ya que parece que tus datos no tienen una estructura fija. Y una cosa más, a qué te refieres con *". . . manejar los esquemas de datos dinámicos de forma más eficiente"*?